# How to force dialect in Flyway test extensions?

Tags: mysql, spring, h2, flyway, dialect

I'm using [Flyway test extensions](https://github.com/flyway/flyway-test-extensions/wiki/Usage-flyway-spring-test) with H2 database and MySQL dialect.

Unfortunately, `@FlywayTest` annotation executes database clean with H2 dialect and ends with error:

```
org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.FlywaySqlException: 
Unable to drop "PUBLIC"."site"
------------------------------
SQL State  : 42S02
Error Code : 42102
Message    : Table "site" not found; SQL statement:
DROP TABLE "PUBLIC"."site" CASCADE [42102-193]


    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SchemaObject.drop(SchemaObject.java:82)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.h2.H2Schema.doClean(H2Schema.java:69)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.Schema.clean(Schema.java:148)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean$4.call(DbClean.java:184)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean$4.call(DbClean.java:181)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.exec
```

However, when I manually run `DROP TABLE PUBLIC.site CASCADE` (no quotes) from console it ends successfully.
How to force dialect in Flyway test extensions?

Answer (score 0):

This is no problem of the annotation `@FlywayTest`. 
The annotation `@FlywayTest` call `flyway.clean()` method.
And Flyway supports for H2 only quoted names for schema and tables. 
See class source code on Github https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/dbsupport/h2/

I think there will be no plan to support H2 feature modes, such like Mysql, Oracle, ....

You can open a issue here https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues